# LISTAG function in oracle giving duplicate values

Tags: oracle

I have two tables `User_details` and `Level_details`.

`User_details` table:

```
ID     Name
1       A
2       B
3       C
4       D
5       E
```

`Level_details` table:

```
trns_id    Lvl   usr_id
66          1      1
66          1      5
77          1      2
77          2      3
66          2      4
66          2      3
77          2      3
66          2      4
```

I am getting the result like:

```
trns_id   Lvl    name
66         1     A, E
66         2     D, C, D
77         1     B
77         2     C, C
```

I am using LISTAG function to get name

`LISTAGG(( SELECT name FROM User_details l WHERE l.usr_id = id and trns_id=t1.trns_id and lvl=t1.lvl ), ',') WITHIN GROUP( ORDER BY lvl ) AS Name`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `distinct` modifier in a `listagg` function call:

```sql
SELECT   trns_id, lvl, LISTAGG(DISTINCT name, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY name)
FROM     level_details l
JOIN     user_details u ON l.usr_id = u.id
GROUP BY trns_id, lvl
```

Answer (score 0):

If your database version doesn't support `DISTINCT` within `LISTAGG`, then you'll have to **first** select distinct values (lines #21 - 23), **then** aggregate them (line #20). Lines #1 - 17 represent sample data; you already have that and don't type it. Query you need begins at line #18.

```
SQL> with user_details (usr_id, name) as
  2    (select 1, 'A' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'B' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'C' from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'D' from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'E' from dual
  7    ),
  8  level_details (trns_id, lvl, usr_id) as
  9    (select 66, 1, 1 from dual union all
 10     select 66, 1, 5 from dual union all
 11     select 77, 1, 2 from dual union all
 12     select 77, 2, 3 from dual union all
 13     select 66, 2, 4 from dual union all
 14     select 66, 2, 3 from dual union all
 15     select 77, 2, 3 from dual union all
 16     select 66, 2, 4 from dual
 17    )
 18  select x.trns_id,
 19         x.lvl,
 20         listagg(x.name, ', ') within group (order by x.lvl) name
 21  from (select distinct u.usr_id, u.name, d.trns_id, d.lvl
 22        from user_details u join level_details d on d.usr_id = u.usr_id
 23       ) x
 24  group by x.trns_id,
 25           x.lvl;

   TRNS_ID        LVL NAME
---------- ---------- ---------------
        66          1 A, E
        66          2 C, D
        77          1 B
        77          2 C

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

LISTAGG gives duplicate values if you have duplicate values

```
trns_id    Lvl   usr_id
77          2      3
77          2      3
```

You can remove duplicates first:

```
select trns_id, Lvl, LISTAGG(name)
from (
    select distinct l.trns_id  l.Lvl, u.name
    from User_details u
        join Level_details l on l.usr_id=u.ID
)
group by trns_id, Lvl
```